# SocketCAN linux no buffer space available

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, buffer, can-bus, socketcan

I want to send a message periodically using socketCAN with this [device](http://canable.io/)

I created a small script to achieve this which looks like this:

```
import os
import time

msg = "1FF#FFFFF00000000000"

os.system("sudo slcand -o -c -f -s6 /dev/serial/by-id/*CANtact* can0")
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 up")
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000") # this does not help

start = time.time()
while True:
    if round(time.time() - start, 1) % 60 == 0.:
        print(str(int((time.time() - start) / 60)) + " minutes")
    os.system("cansend can0 " + msg)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I was already doing some research and found that for some people it worked to set the `txqueuelen`. However, that did not help me. The output of this script looks like this:

```
0 minutes
1 minutes
[...]
15 minutes
16 minutes
18 minutes
write: No buffer space available
write: No buffer space available
write: No buffer space available
write: No buffer space available
write: No buffer space available
write: No buffer space available
[and so on]
```

The device stops sending those messages before that error occurs. The indicator LED for in- and outgoing traffic stops blinking around 10 seconds to a few minutes before error message appears. Also, I cannot read anything on the receiving side. The time it takes until the buffer is full varies gravely, between a few minutes and a few hours. Usually within 10-20 min though.

I had the thought that there might be something like a receiving buffer and because I never read from that that it just fills up. But I do not know whether this is actually the case and also not how to test it or how to flush the buffer or reset it or whatever. I only need to send my messages. I do not care about anything else.

The only solution afterwards is to restart my Raspberry Pi which powers the device.

Comment: Is there anybody listening in the bus?

Comment: No, only my PC at one endpoint and another device receiving those messages.

Comment: This looks suspect: `os.system("sudo slcand -o -c -f -s6 /dev/serial/by-id/*CANtact* can0")` - What do you get when you run `lsusb` on your command line terminal?

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig-parameters need to be set before you bring up a link, but you bring up the link before setting the parameters. So I'm not sure you actually have a txqueuelen of 1000 when you run the script. An output of your `ifconfig can0` might show this.

Try switching the order of the ifconfig-commands.

Instead of:

```
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 up")
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000")`
```

Do:

```
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 txqueuelen 1000")
os.system("sudo ifconfig can0 up")
```

I would personally also add in a command to bring can0 down when the script ends.

Comment: Funnily, I was facing similar issue exactly after 18 minutes using PYUAVCAN, and increasing txqueuelen didn't work. Need to research a little bit more.